# Probability of drawing balls from an urn when the ball color is not known

Tags: probability

There are two balls in an urn. Their colors are unknown - they may be black or white. On the first turn, a ball is drawn from the urn. It is white. It is then replaced into the urn.
On the second turn, a ball is drawn from the urn. It is white. It is then replaced into the urn.

We now know that at least one of the balls in the urn is white. We then draw a third time. What is the probability that this ball is white.

To solve this problem - my first instinct is to say that it must be pretty close to fifty percent. It is definitely possible to draw the same ball twice in a row - 25% chance of this. And, there is a 100% chance one ball is white, with a 50% chance the other ball is white as well. How can I set up and solve a problem using this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's necessary to make some assumption about the *a priori* probability regarding the balls in the urn.  In the solution below, I assume that before beginning the draws, each of the two balls could be black or white with equal probability.

Consider $16$ equally likely trials.  In $4$ trials both of the urn's balls are black.  In $4$ trials both of the urn's balls are white.  In $8$ trials the urn has a black ball and a white ball.

In the $8$ trials where the urn has a black ball and a white ball, you will have $2$ trials where you have drawn $2$ white balls.  In the $4$ trials where the urn has two white balls, you will have $4$ trials where you have drawn $2$ white balls.

Therefore, there is a $\frac 13$ probability that you are in a trial where the urn has a white ball and a black ball, which means there's a $\frac 16$ probability that the next ball you draw will be black, so the probability that your third draw will be a white ball is $\frac 56$.

Answer (score 0):

There are three possibilities: both balls black, one white one black, or both balls white. We will name these possibilities BB, BW, WW.

For each possibility, we find the probability of the observed phenomenon happening. We call this observed phenomenon $\theta$.

For BB, the probability is clearly $0$. So, $p(\theta\mid BB)=0$.

For BW, the probability is $0.5\cdot0.5=0.25$. So, $p(\theta\mid BW)=0.25$.

For WW, the probability is $1\cdot1=1$. So, $p(\theta\mid WW)=1$.

Now, we have to start with some prior distribution, aka, what we think the likelihoods of each of the three possibilities occurring, if we weren't given the information about the first two draws. Let's say that my prior distribution is binomial, i.e, there's a 25% chance of BB, WW ($p(BB),p(WW)=0.25$), and 50% chance of BW ($p(BW)=0.5$). (Why am I choosing this? The question hasn't specified a prior distribution, making it ill-defined. But, I think this is a reasonable choice).

Given our prior, we can compute the posterior distribution by computing $p(\theta\mid X)p(X)$ for each possibility $X$, and then computing $$p(X)=\frac{p(\theta\mid X)p(X)}{\sum_Yp(\theta\mid Y)p(Y)}$$for each $X$. We have $p^*(BB)=0$, $p^*(BW)=\frac13$, $p^*(WW)=\frac23$.

To finish, observe that the probability of a white ball from $BW$ is $\frac12$, and $1$ from $WW$. So, our answer is $p^*(BW)\cdot\frac12+p^*(WW)\cdot1=\frac13\cdot\frac12+\frac23\cdot1=\frac56$.